# Connotations of "mortal" (slang)

Tags: uso-de-palabras, coloquialismos, connotaciones

What does the Spanish word *mortal* mean when used as slang? Does it have a positive or negative connotation towards the thing being described?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Argentina:

In informal conversation, it's roughly equivalent to 'terrific', as in very good, awesome

For example,

> '¡El recital estuvo mortal!'

meaning that it was really good, that I enjoyed it very much.

Comment: At least in Argentina. Not sure about other countries.

Comment: Not in Spain, where it is exactly the opposite. Please qualify your answer for the sake of clarity.

Comment: In Spanish you can have the same meaning with "de muerte"

Comment: @Laura: Indeed.

Comment: That's interesting, If you say that in Mexico, depending on how you say it, it could mean the exact opposite; '¡El recital estuvo mortal!' may actually imply that you almost die from hearing it, but with a slightly different accent and context may mean that it was great...

Answer (score 5):

In Spain, and as far as I understand, it has a powerful negative connotation. For example:

> La reunión fue mortal.
>
> The meeting was awful.

However, and as it sometimes happens with other words, it may as well be used with exactly the opposite meaning. I haven't ever heard it that way, though. Wheat I have heard, as @Laura points out, is *de muerte* meaning "extremely good" or "awesome":

> ¡La comida está de muerte!
>
> The food is awesome!

Comment: We use *mortal* in much the same way in Mexico.

Answer (score 1):

It can also mean "extremely funny" in Spain.

> La broma fue mortal
>
> The joke was extremely funny